# Issue with creating commands with python and sockets

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I am very new to socket programming, But I am using it to create an online text adventure for a friend of mine. I am having trouble creating commands, here is some code the is related to code I saw online that worked.

```
data = sock.recv(RECV_BUFFER)

if data:
   broadcast_data(sock, "\r" + '<' + str(sock.getpeername()) + '> ' + data)


elif data == "/help":
   broadcast_data(sock, "\r"+"HOLY HELL")
   print("help is on the ways")
```

If someone could tell me why this part of my code wont work that would amazing!

Comment: `data` is a string, so doing `if data` won't work... Maybe you mean `if len(data) > 0` or something like that? Also, what does your `broadcast_data` function look like?

Comment: How is it not working? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Besides echoing that your question needs elaboration, I think you'll find [this tutorial on sockets and web-servers](https://ruslanspivak.com/lsbaws-part1/) useful (it has three parts)

Comment: It isnt working in the sense that when I send strings into the server, it doesn't do anything, it just sends it out like a normal word.

Comment: I have found the issue with the code (but not an answer). When the if statement reads the data it reads the first as accurate data and doesn't need to go on to the next if statement. I have tried flipflopping the code, but that makes no difference and I have been trying lots of other things